# DNS adblocker not working on ubuntu

Tags: networking, dns

I am using `Pihole` to block ads across my network and just does not seem to work on ubuntu, tried both my laptop and desktop.

Attached are screenshots of a windows machine an android device and the ubuntu laptop all showing dns configs and forbes website and they are all blocked except the ubuntu one. no ads are blocked on it.

- [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWPAc.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure enough to make a complete answer but this might be a dns caching issue on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Your DNSMasq might be causing the DNS from the pihole to be overlooked.

Try disabling DNSMasq by commenting out the line `dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

You can comment it out by running the following line:

```
sudo bash -c 'sed -i "s/dns=/#dns=/" /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf'
```

Then you can check if the change took effect:

```
:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Then reboot the system for changes to take effect.  After the reboot, check with `nslookup` to see that DNSMasq no longer is serving DNS.  If the `Server:` line shows `127.0.1.1`, that means that DNSMasq is still controlling DNS of the system.

```
:~$ nslookup google.com
Server:     10.0.0.1
Address:    10.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.217.14
```

As you can see, my router IP is `10.0.0.1` which means that DNS is controlled by my router instead of DNSMasq.

Hope this helps!